# An algorithm for grouping by trying without feedback

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, theory

Tagged this as Python because is the most *pseudo-y-code* language in my opinion

I'll explain graphically and the answer can be graphical/theorical too (maybe its the wrong site to post this?)

Let's say I want to make an algorithm that solves a simple digital game for infants (this is not the actual context, its much more complex)

These are the rules :

- There is a square grid seen from above, with a colored lego piece in
  each spot
- You can drag pieces to try and stack on top of each other.
- If their color match, they will stack, leaving the spot of the first
  piece you dragged empty.
- If you move a piece to an empty spot, it will move to that spot
- If their color don't match and you drag one of top of the other, they
  will switch spots.
- The amount of pieces of a same color is randomly generated when a new grid is started.

The goal of the game is to obviously drag pieces of the same color until you only have one stack of each color.

Now here comes question, I want to make a script that solves the game, but it will be "blind", meaning it won't be able to see colors, or track when a match occurs. It will have to traverse in a way that it will ensure it tried all possible "drags"

The main problem for me to even start thinking about this comes from the fact that they swap positions if the script fails to guess the color, and there's no feedback to know that you failed.

Also is the complexity of this calculable? Is it too insane?

Comment: _Tagged this as Python because is the most pseudo-y-code language in my opinion_ hurt my feelings.

Comment: @N.Wouda I meant to say it's a beautiful language to look at :D

Comment: So by consequence (1) the algorithm is allowed to (and will) produce invalid moves, i.e. moves from a square where there is no more block (I assume such moves don't change anything to the grid). (2) the algorithm will always produce the same sequence of moves from any starting position. Is that a correct understanding?

Comment: @trincot yes, lets say it will emulate mouse movements, so it can "try" invalid moves no problem

Comment: And is it true that when you try to move from an empty spot to an occupied spot, the grid will not change? Or will the block on the target spot swap to the first spot?

Comment: @trincot I'm sorry I forgot about that, yes it will, edited the post

Comment: But your edit concerns the opposite situation (moving a block to an empty spot). What if you move "nothing" from an empty spot to an occupied spot? What happens?

Comment: @trincot My edit mentions piece, if you move nothing, nothing happens

Comment: I can think of a pretty stupid algorithem with n^2 complexity when n is the number of squares in the grid. 
for i in xrange(grid.size):
    for j in xrange(i, grid.size):
        grid.move(i, j)
        grid.move(j, i)

This way, if there's a match, the same color will return to its starting position.
If there isn't a match, the original block will return to its place and continue iterating. 
I'm assiming that moving a stack of blocks moves the whole stack, if that's not the situation I need to rethink this :p -EDIT: line breaks don't go well in comment, my bad .-.

Comment: How blind are we talking? Can it feel (detect empty squares or heights)? Why not just repeat each move, to eliminate the swaps? O(2n)== O(n)  What is the question, anyway ... how to do it, or how to calculate the complexity? And remove the python tag, duh.

Comment: Is there any notion of "neighbor" that is important to the rules? If not, then it is not important whether the play area is square, nor that it is two-dimensional (or three, four...). It can just be treated as one-dimensional, by just ordering all the spots in a freely chosen way.

Comment: There's no neighbouring rules, and yes It is completely blind, zero feedback

Comment: The grid is just contextual, can be interpreted as an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try the following:

Suppose we have an m times n grid grid with p different colors. First we work row by row with the following algorithm:

### Column reduction

1. Drag the piece at (1,1) to (1,2), then (1,2) to (1,3) and so on until you reach (1, n)
2. Drag the piece at (1,1) the same way to (1,n-1).
3. Continue till you reach (1, n-p) with the piece moved.

The first step is guaranteed to move the color that was originally at (1,1) to (1,n) and collect all pieces of the same color on its way. 
The succeeding steps collect the remaining colors. After this part of the algorithm we are guaranteed to have only the columns p to n filled, each with a different color.

This we repeat for the remaining m-1 rows. After that the columns 1 to n-p-1 are guaranteed to be empty.

### Row reduction

Now we repeat the same process with the columns, i.e. drag (1, j) to (m, j) for all j >= n-p and then drag (1,j) to (m-1, j).

After this part we are guaranteed to have only filled a p times p subgrid.

### Full grid search

Now we collect each different color by brute force:
Move (p,p) to (p,p+1), (p, p+2), ... (p, n) and then to (p + 1, n), (p+1, n-1), ..., (p+1, p) and then to (p+2, p), ..., (p+2, n) and so on until we reach either (m, p) or (m,n), depending wether p is even or odd.

This step we repeat p times, only that we stop each time on field short of the last one.

As a result only the remaining p fields are filled and each contains a stack of the same color. Problem solved.

To estimate the complexity:

- The row moving part requires n + n-1 + n-2 + ... + n-p= n*(n+1)/2 - (n-p)*(n-p+1)/2=np+(p^2+p)/2=O(n^2) moves per row, hence O(mn^2).
- The column moving part similarly requires O(nm^2) moves.
- The final moving requires p^2 moves for each color, i.e. O(p^3).

If q = max(n,m,p) the complexity is O(q^3).

Note: If we do not know p we could immediately start with the full grid search. We still remain in complexity O(q^3). If, however, p << n or p << m the column and row reduction will reduce the practical complexity greatly.